# Route Issue in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes defined in my global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "Agreements2", // Route name
               "Agreements2/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Agreements", action = "AgreementSummery", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );
             routes.MapRoute(
                "Agreements", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Agreements", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );
```

The latter route works fine, but I cant understand why the first route does not work.

The AgreementSummery method on the Agreements controller is defined as:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AgreementSummery(int? id)
        {

            AgreementsModel model = new AgreementsModel();
            model.SelectedAgreementID = id.Value;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*?  Does navigating to `host/Agreements2/AgreementSummery` not hit the action?

Comment: Not at all, either in the debugger or on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id isn't defined as optional, it is defined as nullable. optional would be if it were assigned a value

```
public ActionResult AgreementSummery(int? id = null)
```